# Incrementing number in angular View (cascaded ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have similar kind of scenario as per the example below, and want to print serial number for each row independent of child, I.E. for each mark record.

**Java script Object structure:**

```
 $scope.childsList = [
        {
        id:12346,
        name : 'Sagar Kulthe',
        marksList : [{subject:'Math', marks: 55}, {subject:'English', marks: 54}, 
                        {subject:'Biology', marks: 65},     
                        {subject:'Physics', marks: 78}]
    },
    {
        id:12346,
        name: 'Amol Pawal',
        marksList : [{subject:'Math', marks: 55}, {subject:'English', marks: 54}, 
                        {subject:'Biology', marks: 65},     
                        {subject:'Physics', marks: 78}]
    },
    {
        id:12346,
        name: 'Tushar Shah', 
        marksList : [{subject:'Math', marks: 55}, {subject:'English', marks:      
                         54},  {subject:'Biology', marks: 65},
                         {subject:'Physics', marks: 78}]
    }
    ];
```

**View:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Sr NO:</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="child in childsList track by $index">
        <tr ng-repeat="mark in marksList track by $index" ng-init="marksIndex = $index">
            <td>{{marksIndex }}</td>
            <td>{{child.name}}</td>
            <td>{{mark.subject}}</td>
            <td>{{mark.marks}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below approach will help you,
https://plnkr.co/edit/CEbyJNevu94LBogYUek7?p=preview

```
<table ng-init="count[0]  = 0">
  <thead>
    <th>Sr NO:</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
  </thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="child in childsList track by $index" ng-init="count[+$index + 1]  = +count[+$index] + child.marksList.length">

    <tr ng-repeat="mark in child.marksList track by $index">

        <td>{{count[+$parent.$index] + $index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{child.name}}</td>
        <td>{{mark.subject}}</td>
        <td>{{mark.marks}}</td>

    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you please explain what does +$index means?

Comment: it is same as parseInt(), another way for typecasting

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to change to this:

```
<td>{{mark.subject}}</td>
<td>{{mark.marks}}</td>
```

Also, i don't think you need to have `ng-init` directive, as `$index` is directly accessible. So, you can change to this:

*Updated as per comment at other answer now deleted*

Suppose this is the controller:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.childsList = [
      ......
    ];
}]);
```

Now in the markup

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="child in childsList track by $index">
    <tr ng-repeat="mark in marksList track by $index" ng-init="marksIndex = $index">
        <td>{{counter+1}}</td><!-- Will start as 1, 2, 3 -->
        <td>{{child.name}}</td>
        <td>{{mark.subject}}</td>
        <td>{{mark.marks}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: i want to print serial numbers for inner ng-repeat. like 1, 2, ... and for next child it should start from previous serial number.

Comment: i.e. for second child serial no. is dependent on previousChild.marksList.length

Comment: @PritamNarkhede then you can have a variable at the scope and just increase it each iteration.

Comment: i have multiple templates of such scenario, so also can we create any generic solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I just do an example hope it can help you
Just need to change number 2 equal your markList length brother.
https://embed.plnkr.co/vkizqh213NN6aUeB9tgQ/

Comment: thanks Nghi. but i want serial number for each marks record. according to your example it starts from 1 for each child

Comment: i have to print table as in template i posted. can you please help i am sucked from couple of days to fix this issue

Comment: I don't understand "serial number for each marks record" Could you describe more detail ? I will try to help

Comment: **like : **
1.  John  English : 2
2.  John  Math : 2
3.  Jessie English : 2
4.  Jessie Math : 2
5.  Johanna English : 2
6.  Johanna Math : 2